# Arduino-ESP8266 Sending URL from a client browser connected to the esp8266 AP and receiving the entered URL in the arduino board

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, esp8266, access-point

I am working on a project where in I have coupled the arduino uno board and an ESP8266 module. I want to send an URL from my browser provided I am connected to the ESP8266 01 AP. For ex, is it possible to send "www.xyz.com" from the browser and it should be received at the ESP8266 module and the request should dumped to the arduino board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done by making the ESP a captive portal, especially since you have set the ESP as an access point. There is an example in the esp wifi library for Arduino. Check out https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino and the examples. In addition, there is a nice WifiManager lib that goes further with a demo of a captive portal at https://github.com/tzapu/WiFiManager
HTH